# How to NOT release keypress in autopy or pyautogui?

Tags: python, pywin32, pyautogui, autopy

When we press a key (such as 'a') in a notebook, and don't release it, we will get aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa......

I want to simulate the key-press in python. So I've coded as follows.

```
import pyautogui, autopy

pyautogui.keyDown('a')
# or
autopy.key.toggle('a')
```

Then, I get just one 'a', even I didn't release the key-press.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Performs a keyboard key press without the release. This will put that
>   key in a held down state.
>
> NOTE: For some reason, this does not seem to cause key repeats like
>   would happen if a keyboard key was held down on a text field.

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    pyautogui.press('a')
```